# jQuery to retrieve selected index value of html select element

Tags: jquery, html

I am developing one website, where multiple dropwn list exists as below:

```
<select name="campaign[nmb][0][trgt_nmb]">
    <option value="">Please Select</option> 
    <option selected="selected" value="1">VAL1</option>
    <option value="2">VAL2</option>
    <option value="3">VAL3</option>
</select>

<select name="campaign[nmb][1][trgt_nmb]">
    <option value="">Please Select</option> 
    <option selected="selected" value="4">VAL4</option>
    <option value="5">VAL5</option>
</select>
```

The above drop-down list generates dynamically. Due to some requirement, I want a particular "Select" field value by name using Jquery.

i.e the value of `campaign[nmb][0][trgt_nmb]` is 1.

Kindly suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please describe it more specific?

Comment: this might be help you **http://jsfiddle.net/p7cve/**

Comment: @jtheman yes, you are right?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the name selector and retrieve the selected value by using `val()`:

```
$('select[name="campaign[nmb][0][trgt_nmb]"]').val();
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/p7cve/1/

Documentation for using attributes as selectors here: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

And for getting values of select's here: http://api.jquery.com/val/